# jmeter if controller with loopin to same http request

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, ruby-jmeter

I have a jmeter test plan with if controller, **I need to loop the same http request until  the if condition become true.**
 [if role==3664v then continue otherwise repeat the same http request page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wyak.jpg)

Comment: seems like you are asking us to write the code for you. what have you tried ? Please post some code that we can help you with

Comment: not like that I am new in jmeter so I shorten the question to avoid complication.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should place your sampler under the [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller) and use the following condition (assumes [__javaScript() function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript)) :

```
 ${__javaScript("${role}" != "3664v",)}
```

You will need to extract this `${role}` variable from the HTTP Request sampler response using [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) or any other matching [Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Assuming this setup JMeter will loop the HTTP Request until `${role}` variable value is not equal to `3664v`. When the `role` becomes `3664v` it will continue.

See [Using the While Controller in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) for more detailed information on implementing the "while loop" concept in JMeter tests.